# Avoid mixed intend with clang-formatter?

Tags: ios, clang-format

In the following line there is two front space, though I would have 1 tab. How can I set config file to get it? Now the config file is listed below.

[image]

```
BasedOnStyle : Chromium 
AlignTrailingComments : true 
BreakBeforeBraces : Allman 
ColumnLimit : 0 
IndentWidth : 4 
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks : false 
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty : true 
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList : true 
PointerBindsToType : false 
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments : 1 
TabWidth : 8 
UseTab : Always
```

Comment: More context, please. At what indent does your snippet start?

Comment: It starts with two space, though only 1 tab should be there.

Comment: clang-format uses `IndentWidth` for that offset. You have it set to 4, but `TabWidth` is 8. Only when you reach 8 spaces will it use a tab instead. Try setting `IndentWidth` to 8.

Comment: @ravnsgaard or set both `IndentWidth` and `TabWidth` to 4?

Comment: Yes, but then you have to ensure that all your editors and viewers are also aware that you're using 4 space tabstops. Practically speaking, every editor assumes 8 spaces per tabstop unless informed otherwise. This is one reason, I prefer to convert all tabs to spaces, btw...

Comment: I like tabs better.

Comment: Your choice. There are pros and cons.